# css @media not re-rendering after going back to the original windows size

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries

I have a normal, general CSS for a website. 
After creating some @media queries to make my elements have different colors, sizes and etc on mobile and different resolutions, everything is fine.

The problem is when I resize the windows from a normal size to a small one, the effects are applied, but when I resize back to the normal one, the css is not refreshed, some "mobile" rules stay there.

How can I re-render the css without the @media rules, not refreshing the page.

This is an example of my HTML:

```
<div class="item">
    <span class="item-foo">FOO </span>
    <span class="item-bar">BAR </span>
</div>
```

With the following css:

```
.item-bar{
    float: right;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 992px){
    .item-foo, .item-bar{
        display: block;
        float: none !important;
    }
}
```

Here is a codepen of it:
[Codepen](http://codepen.io/matheusbaumgart/pen/yyzXpp)

If you resize the view area to a small size until they turn in one span each line and go back to a bigger size, the "bar" element won't be in the right place.

Comment: Can we see the code?

Comment: This seems to be a consistent chrome bug, it's been asked about before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13935255/chrome-float-right-resize-bug

Comment: @JesseKernaghan, yeah man, that's exactly the same bug. Interesting, I'll have a look in their responses. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @JesseKernaghan pointed out in the comments, this is a chrome bug.
The easy-fix would be increasing the specificity for the button fixes this, as suggested by @SeanKeating.

In this question's case, adding this style fixed the problem:

```
.item .item-bar{
  float: right;
  display: inline;
}
```

Here is the codepen updated with the easy-fix
http://codepen.io/matheusbaumgart/pen/yyzXpp